# Clojure idiomatic solution to return variables as map

Tags: variables, dictionary, clojure

I am currently learning clojure and I very much like it. However I come from an emacs-lisp background and I am still a bit confused when it comes to destructuring.
Currently I receive a database-query with a lot of keys. I break them down in different variables via destructuring, and finally, after creating a couple of new values via let, I reconstruct a hash-map as a return value. 
The code looks like this:

```
(fn [{:keys [metre _id num filedate divtype section sandhi lines grammar devanagari filename notes trans sectionnumber fileauthor lang]}]
 (cond
   ;;when we have chinese
   (= lang "zh")
    (let [newgrammar (apply str (map (fn [{:keys [word position line tag] }]
                                       (str "<span class=\"dropt\">" word
                                            "<span style=\"width:500px;\"><font color=\"green\">Word:</font>" word
                                            "<br><font color=\"red\">Function:</font> " tag
                                            "<br><font color=\"blue\">Meaning:</font> " (db/get-chindic-meaning word tag)
                                            "</span></span>")) grammar)) 
          newtrans (first (map #(last (last %)) trans))]              
      (hash-map :metre metre :id _id :num num :filedate filedate :divtype divtype :section section :sandhi sandhi :lines lines :grammar newgrammar :devanagari devanagari :filename filename :notes notes :trans newtrans :sectionnumber sectionnumber :fileauthor fileauthor :lang lang))
```

This is just one extract, there are many different conditions following. So there is a lot of code wich feels totally unnecessary to me.
I guess this is ugly and certainly not the way it *should* be. Any suggestions on how to do this right? Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can capture the whole map this way:

```
user> (defn my-fun [{:keys [a b c d e] :as params-map}]
    (assoc params-map
           :a 200
           :b 100))
#'user/my-fun
user> (my-fun {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5})
{:a 200, :b 100, :c 3, :d 4, :e 5}
```

so you just update some specific values in a map, without redefining it.
also take a look at `update`, it might be useful in this case

as for me, I would rewrite your fn like this:
(move out some functions and use `update`)

```
(defn update-grammar [grammar]
  (apply str (map (fn [{:keys [word position line tag] }]
                    (str "<span class=\"dropt\">" word
                         "<span style=\"width:500px;\"><font color=\"green\">Word:</font>" word
                         "<br><font color=\"red\">Function:</font> " tag
                         "<br><font color=\"blue\">Meaning:</font> "     (db/get-chindic-meaning word tag)
                         "</span></span>")) grammar)))

(defn update-trans [trans] (first (map #(last (last %)) trans)))

(fn [{:keys [metre _id num filedate divtype section 
             sandhi lines grammar devanagari filename 
             notes trans sectionnumber fileauthor lang]
      :as params-map}]
 (cond
   ;;when we have chinese
   (= lang "zh")
   (-> params-map
       (update :grammar update-grammar)
       (update :trans update-trans))
```

you see, now you can even remove `grammar` and `trans` from `:keys` vector, as you don't need them anymore

Comment: Great, thank you very much. This is highly useful for me. :)